# How to seek() at beginning of file that created using FileInputStream()

Tags: java

How to seek to beginning of file?

I need to read the file again (e.g. data changed by other process/application), hence prefer not to `close`/`open()` again.

```
File patternDirectory = new File("/temp/conf_file");
FileInputStream dataInput = new FileInputStream(new File(patternDirectory .getAbsolutePath().toString()));

private void readfile() {
    int len;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    if ((len = dataInput.read(buffer)) != -1)
        System.out.println("Read OK:" + len); 
    /* File is small and this will reach at end of file*/       
}
```

Comment: Do you wish to read the file from the beginning once it has changed? I don't think other non-Java processes or applications will be allowed to open the file if you don't close it in Java in the first place.

Comment: Capitalize letters where needed, also formatted method's names.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `bufferedReader` to read the data along with a `FileInputStream`. This will work if the file has been closed, if not, as said by [@bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446426/how-to-seek-at-beginning-of-file-that-created-using-fileinputstream#comment47059807_29446426) I don't think this can be done in Java.

He is an example of how you could use a `bufferedReader` and a `FileInputStream`:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(//file path);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
```

And when you want to reposition to the start of the file use

```
fin.getChannel().position(0);
BufferedReader foo = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
```

This will reposition with a new reader back to the start of the file.

Read more about the `BufferedReader` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

Comment: @SukumarGhorai What is the issue you're having?

Comment: fin.getChannel().position(0);  => this is fixed the issue. thx lot.

Comment: @SukumarGhorai This simply resets the reader to the first character of the given file.